# Broken 2 Way Data Binding

Tags: angularjs

Going through a [Forms Angular2 tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html). And I get to a part where my code isn't doing what the tutorial explains should happen. So before I reach a conclusion that Angular2 Beta has a bug maybe someone could try this out.

It's a problem around the 2 way data binding of the "Powers dropdown" where a user input change isn't being reflected in the model. The 2 way binding occurs with:

`<select class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="model.power">`

**EDIT:**

See full code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TCqnhkjRpYNlEQMlta05)

When you run the code keep an eye on the `"{"id":18,"name":"Dr IQ","power":"Really Smart","alterEgo":"Chuck Overstreet"} "` output. You will notice that it changes as you edit the 2 txt inputs but that changes to the dropdown are not reflected in this output.

Comment: Have you ever tried to use plunkr? http://plnkr.co/ If you put your code into a plunker people can run it and debug it.

Comment: Adding to @RedCricket Please see mcve: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: maybe I do not understand your question, but when I change the super power from "Really Smart" to "Super Hot" I see `{"id":18,"name":"Dr IQ","power":"Super Hot","alterEgo":"Chuck Overstreet"}` as one would expect.

Comment: That did help! Strangely enough, the problem only appears in Firefox (Iceweasel) but works fine in Google Chrome (Chronium). Thanks for your help. Makes me wonder if this is common with AngularJS since it is backed by Google...

Comment: I was using a Chrome browser btw.